# How to find a continuous and positive $f$, such that the ODE $x''(t)=f(x(t))$ doesn't have unique solution given some initial value?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**As the title**. I want to find a continuous $f$, such that the ODE $x''(t)=f(x(t))$ has more than one solutions when the initial value $x(0), x'(0)$ are given.

I hope $f(x)\neq0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So assume $f$ is always positive.

Is it possible to find one?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried? Where does the problem come from? Also, are you interested in the second order problem $x'' = f(x)$ or the first order problem $x' = f(x)$? For the second order problem the answer is very simple.

Comment: I have the question when I am thinking about Newton's laws of motion. $x''=\sqrt{x}$ doesn't have unique solution given x(0)=0 and x'(0)=0. And by the way, I forgot to mention the initial value x'(0) should also be given.

Comment: But $\sqrt{x}$ is not always positive, so I hope to find a better example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @whpowell96 I don't think it's so simple.  The uniqueness theorem is not an "if and only if".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Under the stated assumptions, solutions of the equation are unique.**

To see this, first observe that WLOG $x(0) = 0$, since $y(\cdot) = x(\cdot) - x(0)$ solves $y''(t) = f(y(t) + x(0))$, which is an equation of the same type.

Also observe that $x'$ is strictly increasing in the existence interval of the solution, and thus $x'$ can change its sign at most once. *In particular $x(t)$ cannot be constant on any interval, which is the mechanism by which solutions of $x' = f(x)$ may be non-unique.*

Now reduce the order of the problem in the usual way: Multiplying with x'(t) and integrating, we see that
$$
\left( x'(t)\right)^2 = \left( x'(0)\right)^2 + 2F(x(t))
$$
where $F(z) = \int_0^z f(\sigma) d \sigma$. Consequently, if e.g. $x'(0) < 0$, then
$$
x'(t) = -\sqrt{(x'(0))^2 + 2 F(x(t))}
$$
on the set where $x' < 0$. The right hand side is continuously differentiable as a function of $x(t)$, thus the solution is unique on the set  $\{t \, : \, x'(t) < 0\}$. This set is an open interval.

In a completely similar way, the solution is unique on the set  $\{t \, : \, x'(t)> 0\}$.

It therefore remains to show that if $x'' = f(x),  \, 
x'(t_0) = 0, \, x(t_0) = x_0$, the solution is unique in small intervals that are bounded on one side by $t_0$. WLOG we may assume again that $t_0 = 0, \, x_0 = 0$.

One can now use the usual method of separating variables. To show e.g. that the solution is unique in some interval $(0, \delta)$, set as before for $z \ge 0$
$$
F(z) = \int_0^z \, f(\sigma) d \sigma, \, G(z) = \int_0^z \frac{d \sigma}{\sqrt{2 F(\sigma)}} 
$$
Note that $F(z) \ge \varepsilon z$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ for $0 < z < \delta$ and therefore $G(z)$ is well defined and strictly increasing in $z$. As usual, $\frac{d}{dt}G(x(t)) = 1$ and $G(x(0)) = 0$, implying $G(x(t)) =  t$. Therefore $x(t)$ is unique on $(0,\delta)$.

Comment: I think you are right! Thanks a lot!